# How to get all records except one using Groupby and RowNo?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with SQL Server, and I need to update all the duplicate records (invalid) except one record (valid).

I don't know why my query is not returning rowno - I always get 1:

```
select *
from TABLE_NAME
inner join 
    (select  
         Contact_EmailID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by Contact_EmailID order by Contact_EmailID) RN,
         COUNT(*) AS COUNTM
     from 
         TABLE_NAME
     group by 
         Contact_EmailID
     having  
         Contact_EmailID != '') as EmailDet On EmailDet.Contact_EmailID = TABLE_NAME.Contact_EmailID
where 
    EmailDet.COUNTM > 2
```

I want all records with a `RN` greater than 1 so I can update them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Selecting  Duplicate Rows I use the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    select ID,Contact_Name,Contact_EmailID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Contact_EmailID order by Contact_EmailID) RN
    FROM AtsTool_ContactDetails 
    WHERE Contact_EmailID != '' and EmailVerifiedResponce='valid'
    )T 
    WHERE RN>1
```

for Update UNIQUE EMAIL on select query

```
;with DeleteDuplicate AS
(
select ID,Contact_Name,Contact_EmailID, Status, EmailVerifiedResponce, 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Contact_EmailID order by Contact_EmailID) RN
FROM AtsTool_ContactDetails 
WHERE Contact_EmailID != '' and EmailVerifiedResponce = 'valid'
)

UPDATE DeleteDuplicate SET [Status] = 0, EmailVerifiedResponce = 'invalid' WHERE RN>1
```

Thus from above update query, only single entry of email will be available and others are updated as status = 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
select *
from TABLE_NAME
inner join 
(
    SELECT  Contact_EmailID             
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE Contact_EmailID !=''
    GROUP BY Contact_EmailID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as EmailDet
On EmailDet.Contact_EmailID=TABLE_NAME.Contact_EmailID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try ...

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Contact_EmailID ORDER BY Contact_EmailID ) AS rowNum
    FROM table_name
) tempTable
WHERE tempTable.rowNum > 1;
```

The inner `SELECT` statement should place a row number next to each record that is unique within the group of email addresses.  You should then be able to choose which rows you do or do not wish to access, such as with the outside `SELECT` statement.

Note : I haven't been able to test this in the absence of any suitable test data, but I hope that where the source list is unsorted it will continue the sequence for each ID as opposed to restarting at 1 whenever an ID is different to the previous ID even when the current ID has been encountered before.  If that problem does occur then please try...

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Contact_EmailID ORDER BY Contact_EmailID ) AS rowNum
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY Contact_EmailID
) tempTable
WHERE tempTable.rowNum > 1;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.